# Call an AsyncTask inside a Thread

Tags: android

I am working in an android application and I want to call an AsyncTask from my UI main thread. For that I want to call my AsyncTask from a thread.

This is the method that I call from my main UI thread. This is working correctly

```
  CommonAysnk   mobjCommonAysnk = new CommonAysnk(this, 1);
  mobjCommonAysnk.execute();
```

CommonAysnk is my AsyncTask class.I want to pass my activity and an integer parameter to the AsyncTask constructor. How can I call this from a thread as shown below method.

```
 Thread t = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {                       
            CommonAysnk   mobjCommonAysnk = new CommonAysnk(this, 1);
            mobjCommonAysnk.execute();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {

                    }}};                            
            t.start();
```

When I tried to call it from a Thread and I am not able to pass the activity parameter correctly.

This is CommonAysnk class. Please look into it

```
public class CommonAysnk extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, String> {

    private Common mobjCommon = null;
    private Activity mobjActivity = null;
    private int mcallIntentcond = 0;
    private ProgressDialog mProcessDialog = null;

    public CommonAysnk(Activity activity, int condition) {
        mobjActivity = activity;
        mcallIntentcond = condition;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mProcessDialog.dismiss();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mobjCommon = new Common();
        mProcessDialog = mobjCommon.showProgressDialog(mobjActivity, "",
                "Loading...", false);
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(URL... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
        switch (mcallIntentcond) {
        case 1:
            Intent i=new Intent(mobjActivity, Home.class);
            mobjActivity.startActivity(i);
            mobjActivity.finish();
            break;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

How can we sole this. Thanks

Comment: first thing that I notice is that you're starting activities withing your `doInBackground()`.. why don't you do it inside `onPostExecute()`  ? also you're starting a thread and then calling the asycTask within a thread.. you really need to reconsider what you're doing!!

Comment: Please look in to my question A.A. I am trying to start my AsynkTask from another Thread.There are issued when we start AsynkTask from the UI main thread. Refer this link for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception  I think we have to to all the functions in doInBackground() in AsynkTask. Even if I call my Intent in onPostExecute() how can I solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason to run AsyncTask within a thread like this, you can call this on the UI thread. AsyncTask manages the threading for you.

The code you enter in the doInBackground method is automatically run in a background thread, the other methods on your AsyncTask are run on the UI thread and you can directly interact safely with the UI.

Comment: Hi Philio ,
Thanks for the reply. There are some problems when we run AsyncTask in UI main thread. The error is android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. Please look into the link for further information.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: To clarify what I mean is you can simply instantiate and run the AsyncTask from the UI thread, e.g. new SomeAsyncTask().run() rather than running it within a thread.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use **this** directly from inside a thread as the context changes from your MainActivity to the thread class. So you need to do the following,

```
CommonAysnk   mobjCommonAysnk = new CommonAysnk(ActivityName.this, 1);
```

And you may run AsyncTask from within a thread, no hard and fast rules with regard to that.

Comment: Hi Royston,Thanks for the reply.
The constructor CommonAysnk(Class<SplashScreen>, int) is undefined. Still I get this error. Pleasesolve this

Comment: Ok, i get it, change to CommonAysnk   mobjCommonAysnk = new CommonAysnk();

Comment: Then how can I pass the parameter values to the CommonAysnk class constructor.

Comment: You can, remove "this" as you need not pass the context, just pass the number "1"

Comment: Please look into my question. I have updated with my CommonAysnk class.

Comment: Ok, so firstly, u need not pass the Activity to AsyncTask. So just pass the Integer. Secondly, u dont need a constructor, your arguments passed can be acessed, request you to google the same. Thirdly, in switch case, instead of returning null, return a valid string. You can use this String in onPostExecute() to launch you Intent. Since onPostExecute() runs on UI thread u can use "this" there without needing a context. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 CommonAysnk mobjCommonAysnk = new CommonAysnk(ClassName.this, 1);
 mobjCommonAysnk.execute();
```

Comment: hi,
The constructor CommonAysnk(Class<SplashScreen>, int) is undefined. Still I get this error.

Comment: how did you define the constructor?

Comment: Please look into my question. I have updated with my CommonAysnk class.

Answer (score 1):

It is mandatory to call `asynctask` only from main thread,
else it may crash at run time when we try to touch UI from `onPreExecute` or `onProgressUpdate` or `onPostExecute` functions.